# using phpunit without composer

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, composer-php, phar

I'm trying to instal PHPunit on an old system,
I'm dealing with several phar issues,

from now i've managed to have PHPunit running, to have my autoload working, also the pPHPunit, but now, it is trying to call composer.

i Had to add an extention "PHPUnit/Extensions/Story", it's also working, but now, i've got to manage composer...

I tried to add the phar, to extract the phar , ... but nothing seems to work (if "Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader.php" work, then I've got an "Instantiator\Instantiator.php" missing...)

So, is it possible to have PHPunit running without composer?

Comment: What command are you using to run your tests?

Comment: Hi, I use the command line with --bootstrap , i juste solved my problem a post a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can simply use composer to handle only PHPunit and it's dependencies.

So the easiest way is to simply use composer. There is nothing wrong at using composer for just a small part of your dependencies. In fact, for some (small) projects I even use it for no dependency at all (only to handle the autoloading).

You can use it in the subdirectory test, or more conventionally at the root of the project.

Comment: Sorry if I just answered to a younger me, but my previous self response was wrong on so many levels...

Answer (score -1):

I juste solved the problem :

despite I called "spl_autoload_register" for my own framework afeter including PHPunit and Composer"s ones, mine was sometimes called before, so I juste added a whitelisting in my autoloader (see $tabLibCommunPrefixes):

```
function phpunit_bootstrap_autoload($class_name) {
    $prefixe = substr($class_name, 0, strpos($class_name, '_'));

    $tabLibCommunPrefixes = array('Smarty', 'Zend', 'Bvb', 'Composer', 'domxml-php4-compat', 'FirePhp', 'Mobile', 'Nusoap', 'Pear', 'phing', 'PhpMailer', 'phpThumb', 'Sitra', 'Smarty3', 'smarty', 'test', 'upload', );
    if (in_array($prefixe, $tabLibCommunPrefixes)) {
        require_once str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```